# Username in python-social-auth

Tags: python, openid, django-socialauth

I want to use [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) for my webservice but I'm not 100% sure how it works:

When I sign up with my github account (let's say my github account is called joe) then python-social-auth creates a new user named joe and `user.username` also joe.
But what happens if another user wants to sign up, i.e. using a google account, but this user has the google username joe.

What happens on my webservice then? will python-social-auth complain and say that there is already a user named joe, or will it be able to distinguish the github user and the google user?

and will the `user.username` be joe for both?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`python-social-auth` will create a unique username for each user in case of a collision, the default resolving method is to append a hash to the end of the username, so it will became `joed41d8cd98f00...`, the method that takes care of that is here https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/pipeline/user.py#L9-L53.

You can override the default behavior by replacing that method in the pipeline (or adding another after that one which applies some transformation to the generated username).